# uni level MLM Calculation. i have: User-> HasMany::Users, User-> HasMany::trading , trading-> HasOne::trading_data->balance | Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, recursion, mlm

[image]

in this picture all are users.

```php
User::hasMany(User::class, 'ref_by');

User::hasMany(Trading::class);

Trading::hasOne(TradingData::class);
```

Now i want to sum `balance` from `TradingData` for user(B).

Where B hasMany User and They also hasMany Users.

Comment: I think you'll need to use recursive function here which adds balance of each child, checks if child has another child and returns sum of balance of child and returned children balances